# How to count while loop output PHP SQL

Tags: php, sql, binding, parameters, count

**Le solution**

I arrived here with the help of Brian and W3Schools

This is garbage, it doesn't work... I can't output the loop to a specific location ahhh

```
$rows2 = array();
while($stmt->fetch()){
echo $date.'<br>'.$stratoparse.'<br>'.'<br>';
$rows2[] = $stratoparse;
$rows3[] = $date;
}

for($i=0;$i<=$num_rows;$i++){
echo $rows3[$i].'&nbsp;'.$rows2[$i].'<br>'.'<br>';
}
```

outputs

01-05-2015
sample 3

01-05-2015
sample 2

01-05-2015
sample

01-05-2015 sample 3

01-05-2015 sample 2

01-05-2015 sample

**Initial post**

So I am trying to store the output of a while loop query. In a stand alone .php file the while loop outputs the data fine. But when I'm trying to store it, eg. start the loop by POST eg. a search submission, the while loop does not "execute properly" as it does in the standalone script. I will provide both parts of the code.

What I'm trying to do is count the number of columns that satisfy the SELECT statement, knowing that I would use range(1,this number) to store the while output... if there is an easier more direct approach, that would be great as well.

This is the standalone code, not complete just the select. It does work, the rows are echoed out in descending order.

What appear to be spelling errors are not spelling errors, the server access information has username with one arm so I differentiated by using two r's.

```
<?php
$stmt=$link->prepare('SELECT stratoparse,date FROM stock WHERE user=? AND keyphrase=? ORDER BY ID DESC');
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$userrname,$keyphrase);
$stmt->execute();

$stratoparse=null;
$date=null;
$stmt->bind_result($stratoparse,$date);

while($stmt->fetch()){
echo $date.'<br>'.$stratoparse.'<br>'.'<br>';
}
?>
```

This is the code I'm trying to use, I actually don't really need to post the second part. The code above would be triggered by a POST event, and then the output is stored and echoed in the HTML

I'm trying to apply this solution found on stackoverflow as well

```
$store_array = range( 1, 5);

$i = 1; 
$store_array = array();
while( $i <= 5)
{
     $store_array[] = $i;
     $i++;
}
```

**UPDATE**

This is the output when I run the test .php file

01-05-2015
sample 3

01-05-2015
sample 2

01-05-2015
sample

010

You can see the two num_rows echoed are 0, the 1 in between is a bool(true) I think when I echo $stmt->execute();

This is the code minus the login info

```
$link = new mysqli("$servername", "$username", "$password", "$dbname");
$link2 = new mysqli("$servername", "$username", "$password", "$dbname");

$stmt=$link->prepare('SELECT stratoparse,date FROM stock WHERE user=? AND keyphrase=? ORDER BY ID DESC');
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$userrname,$keyphrase);
$stmt->execute();
$num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
$stratoparse=null;
$date=null;
$stmt->bind_result($stratoparse,$date);
while($stmt->fetch()){
echo $date.'<br>'.$stratoparse.'<br>'.'<br>';
}


echo $num_rows;

$stmt2=$link2->prepare('SELECT COUNT(keyphrase) FROM stock WHERE user=? AND keyphrase=?');
$stmt2->bind_param('ss',$userrname,$keyphrase);
echo $stmt->execute();
$stmt2->bind_result($keyphrase);
$num_rows2 = $stmt2->num_rows;

echo $num_rows2;
```

Comment: Your code is still missing '$stmt->store_result()' after you execute and before you assign $num_rows to $stmt->num_rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean number of rows and not number of columns, there is no need for a while loop - you can get the [number of rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php) returned directly from the SQL statement:

```
$stmt->store_result();
$num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
$stmt->close();
```

The number of columns you already know from your SELECT query.

EDIT: Based on your comments below, you want to store the results of your query for later. Unfortunately, using prepared statements it is somewhat messier than the standard msyql result. You can see some examples in the documention for [bind_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php), but the basic idea is this:

```
$rows = array();
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $rows[] = array('key1'=>$field1, 'key2'=>$field2, ...);
}
```

Not complete code, of course, but once you flesh it out, you will end up with an array of rows where each element is the row as an associative array, much like you would get with a mysql result's fetch_assoc() function.

Comment: The output is zero. Yes I did mean number of rows, sorry about that. I tried to use the num_rows for both SELECT stratoparse,date and SELECT COUNT(keyphrase) statements, both output zero.

Comment: Check your SELECT statement, then - it is very likely that it didn't return any rows with the input you gave it.

If you are querying passwords, for example, usually you retrieve the password from the database and then compare it to the password in POST using PHP's password_verify us2.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: I could do it by using sessions but that doesn't seem safe to me. I would send the inputs that would have been bound to session values and then these session values would have been assigned to variables. The variables would then be used in SQL statements. I can accomplish that but again it does not seem safe.

Comment: The SELECT statement works, I get the output of the rows that match the AND query of username and keyphrase.

Comment: Can you show your updated code? You should be able to get the number of rows after running the query and before you close it.

Comment: You are getting the num_rows from a SELECT COUNT query... that won't work. You should get the number of rows from your original query, and you don't need to make a second query at all.

Comment: Oops, that's my bad. It should be $stmt->store_result(), not bind_result(), called before you try to access the number of rows.

Comment: Did you feel that? I just hugged you. So the count works, 3 was outputted. That's great now I have to figure out how to store / retrieve. I tried to look up how store_result() works. I need to store the arbitrary number of rows then output them anywhere on the front end section.

Comment: Lol, thanks, I did feel that xD To store the number of rows, just assign it to a variable: $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows. Now you can use '$num_rows' anywhere you want, even after closing the statement.

Comment: See I haven't actually solved the initial problem which is to store the output of the while loop and pull it out anywhere. Eg. when a person presses' submit, the while loop is ran, the output is stored, then displayed in the appropriate location. I wanted to know how to count rows because the array solution needed a number of rows / array size. But this doesn't seem to be solving my problem.

Comment: Still I'm happy to have learned how to count the number of rows with parameter binding so thank you for that.

Comment: Updated the answer with a link and short explanation of storing results from a prepared statement into an array.

Comment: Feel free not to explain, I've asked a lot already. I don't understand that array. I have a variable row count output of two things which I am assuming is what you mean by field: date,stratoparse so if stored in an array I would think it looks like ahhh can't press enter, date1,stratoparse1 date2,stratoparse2, etc... I actually don't know if this will solve my problem. I'll update again to be absolutely clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: It's not that I'm not willing to explain, it's that there are already full examples in the link. Look at the user comments below the official documentation.

Comment: No it's okay. I figured it out. I just read up on PHP on W3Schools, gotta love that place. I'm going to post the solution in the main question. It's actually not what I want fully eg. gotta condense the array to one, but it does work. <- so American, it's not broke why fix it...